# Automatically adapt formula in conditional formatting in Excel 2007/10

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I'm using MS Excel 2007 and I've defined this **conditional formatting** for a set of cells:

`=NOT(ISBLANK($D$21))`   ... then change the background + font.

I want to copy this format only for hundreds of rows (cell sets). But when I `copy` it =
paste special - Formats
, it will copy the format, but it references the same style. That means if I change D21 to D22, it will affect the other set too. What more I want to be able to say Excel: Increment D21 for each row !

Do you have any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the formula without the $, i.e.,

```
=NOT(ISBLANK(D21))
```

Comment: Rofl. Looks like I'm missing some excel basics .. Thank you !